# Swift inheritance and classes

Tags: ios, swift, class, inheritance

I am learning swift on my own but I cannot manage to make this code run, I am trying to create a class "Inhabitant" inheriting from Person class with a new "Country" property, have 2 initializers:
- one that takes firstname and lastname and sets the country to an empty String
- one that takes firstname, lastname and country
and create a computed property description of String type that return a the firstname, lastname and country separated by a space

```
class Person {
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var fullname: String {
        return firstname + " " + lastname
    }

    init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
    }
}

    class Inhabitant: Person {
    var country: String? = nil
    var description: String {
        return firstname + " " + lastname + " " + country ?? ""
    }
    override init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        super.init(firstname: <#T##String#>, lastname: <#T##String#>)
        self.country = ""
    }
    init(firstname: String, lastname: String, Country: String) {
        super.init(firstname: <#T##String#>, lastname: <#T##String#>)
    }
}

func tst() {
    let perso = Inhabitant(firstname: "toto", lastname: "bobo")
    print(perso)
}
```

The code won't run:

```
Editor placeholder in source file
```

Comment: Change `<#T##String#>` to some String. The easy way is select it and type if it is still a "live" placeholder; otherwise you'll just have to do it by hand. Learn about Xcode's "autocomplete" feature. What you want are `firstname` and `lastname` here. In other words, you just want to pass the incoming `firstname` and `lastname` values up the inheritance chain to the `super.init` call.

Comment: In Xcode, see the word `String` after `super.init(firstname:`? That's an "editor placeholder". You need to replace that with something.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for resetting my brain - early morning here!

Comment: But why should I replace it ? I want to call this string inside the tst function, not in the initialiser

Comment: You need to pass the variables into where those placeholders are. i.e.  `super.init(firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname)`

Comment: why would I pass variables, this would mean that the initalised objects will always have the same value ? or they will take this value by default if none is provided ?

Comment: also why do I have this error for the desc variable: value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String' and coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'

Comment: You are passing the variable from the function input to it's superclass constructor.

Comment: For your question about the optional, that means you are trying to use an optional value somewhere that does not take an optional.  The `??` operator allows you to use an optional in places where you can also provide a backup value.  For instance, say `x` is of type `String?`(optional String) `let y = x ?? "someString"`.  This will set `y` to the value of `x` if it has a value, otherwise it will be set to whatever the string is after the `??`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
class Person {
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var fullname: String {
        return firstname + " " + lastname
    }

    init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
    }
}

class Inhabitant: Person {
    var country: String? = nil
    var description: String {
        //1
        return "\(firstname) \(lastname) \(country ?? "")"
    }
    override init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        //2
        super.init(firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname)
        self.country = ""
    }
    init(firstname: String, lastname: String, country: String) {
        super.init(firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname)
        self.country = country
    }
}

func tst() {
    let perso = Inhabitant(firstname: "toto", lastname: "bobo")
    let perso2 = Inhabitant(firstname: "toto", lastname: "bobo", country: "Belgium")
    print(perso.fullname)
    print(perso2.description)
}

tst()
```

**Explanations:**

1. String interpolation in swift are done with this syntax, cf [swift programming language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292)
2. When you override the initialiser, what you want is to pass the arguments you receive to your super initialiser.